# MDaemon Minger UDP datagram request

Tags: c#, udp

I am attempting to construct a MDaemon Minger protocol UDP request as defined in the following [specification](https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/draft-hathcock-minger-06.pdf). Assuming I am interpreting the spec correctly, for a mailbox of `user@foo.com` with a shared-secret of `U5TttqcKSw0jJcPHrHWb` is this what the string version of the request should look like?

`user@foo.com d=QTNCMDgxNDEwMUIzRkJDNTM4NTUzQjg1NkU5Rjk2Mjg=`

I get a response back, however the status code is always a '2' which indicates that the credentials passed along in the request were invalid. The server is not setup to allow anonymous lookups -- thus my need to send the credentials. I suspect that I am not doing something correct in the way I am building the credentials parameter.

I believe I am sending the shared secret credential properly with the request, however the server is stating that it is invalid. I do not understand what I am doing wrong with the packaging and transmission of shared secret credential. I am hoping that a fresh set of eyes on the protocol specification and my sample code will be able to help me find the credential transmission issue.

I am arriving at this via the following code:

```
public bool IsValidUser(string emailAddress)
{

    var digestText = _sharedSecret + ":" + emailAddress;
    var digest = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(CreateMD5(digestText));
    string query = emailAddress + " d=" + System.Convert.ToBase64String(digest);
    var sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(query);

    _udpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);

    IPEndPoint remoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
    var results = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_udpClient.Receive(ref remoteIpEndPoint));

    return false;
}

public static string CreateMD5(string input)
{
    // Use input string to calculate MD5 hash
    using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
    {
        byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
        byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

        // Convert the byte array to hexadecimal string
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("X2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a closer examination of the specification and what I was doing I realized my error. I was needlessly taking the returned byte array of the hash values and converting them to a hex string. It did not occur to me that I should (could) just Base64 encode the resultant byte array containing the MD5 hash.

Working code below:

```
internal bool IsValidUser(string emailAddress)
{

    var digestText = _sharedSecret + ":" + emailAddress;

    byte[] hashBytes;
    using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
    {
        hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(digestText));
    }

    var digest = System.Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
    string query = emailAddress + " d=" + digest;
    var sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(query);

    _udpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);

    IPEndPoint remoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
    var results = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_udpClient.Receive(ref remoteIpEndPoint));

    //code which looks at results and return true/false here....
    return false;
}
```